# Evaluating $\int_0^1\left(\int_0^\infty\frac{x^2}{(x^3z^3+1)(x^3+1)}dx\right)dz$

Tags: definite-integrals

I was trying to obtain some interesting identity and refresh my mathematics, as same manner and tricks showed in [1] for modified functions (my modified function that I write in the integrand and my modified *Fact*, see **My attempt** if you want/need to know it). My question is

> **Question.** Can you to evaluate $$\int_0^1\left(\int_0^\infty\frac{x^2}{(x^3z^3+1)(x^3+1)}dx\right)dz.$$
>   Thanks in advance.

**My attempt:** First we prove

*Fact.* The algebraic identity holds $$\frac{1}{z^3-1}\left(\frac{2x^2z^3}{x^3z^3+1}-\frac{2x^2}{x^3+1}\right)=\frac{2x^2(z^3-1)}{(x^3z^3+1)(x^3+1)}.$$

Thus previous integral reduces to $$\int_{0}^1\frac{\log z}{z^3-1}dz.$$
By this way I can use/work a change of variable $u=\log z$ and $dv=dz/(z^3-1)$, decomposition in simple fraction to $1/(z^3-1)=a/(z-1)+B/(z^2+z+1)$, gives $A=1/3,B=-2/3$ and it is known that $\int dx/(1+x+x^2)=2\arctan((2x+1)/\sqrt{3})/\sqrt{3}$. But I obtain troubles to evaluate the integration limits.

In the other hand, using Fubini we have 
$$\int_0^\infty\frac{x^2}{x^3+1}\left(\int_0^1\frac{dz}{x^3z^3+1}\right)dx,$$
then I can work the change $u^2=x^3z^3$, $dz=2zdu/3u$ to write 
$$\int_0^1\frac{dz}{x^3z^3+1}=\frac{1}{x}\int_{0}^{x^{3/2}}\frac{2}{3}\frac{u^{-1/3}}{u^2+1}du.$$

Summarizing I don't how continue to evaluate at least one time the integral (the author of [1] uses two times Fubini and a MacLaurin expansion to obtain his statement). I do not think that my modification will be useful, but I want to learn to integrate at least to one manner previous integral (if it is possible find an identity is the best (is not required))

**References:**

[1] James Harper, Another Simple Proof of $1+\frac{1}{2^2}+\frac{1}{3^2}+\cdots=\frac{\pi^2}{6}$, The American Mathematical MONTHLY, **2003**, pages 540-541.

Comment: Please, do not close or delete the question. It is a nice problem which could be of a lot of interest for many participants. By the way, I am next door to you !

Comment: My english is bad,  to me close is choose an answer @ClaudeLeibovici

Comment: Mejor, amigo ! Hasta pronto. I honestly think that Achille's answer is better than mine.

Comment: @achillehui can you tell me explicitely what have I to prove to use Tonelli in your answer? Then I can save my computations in a comment and don't disturb to you more, thanks. I am trying use Tonelli in other recent post, I know that when I was student I studied it, and I put my eyes on https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fubini%27s_theorem#Tonelli.27s_theorem but I want know in easy words what statements I have to prove. Very thanks much

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Substitute $z = e^{-t}$,

$$\begin{align}
\int_0^1 \frac{\log z}{z^3-1} dz &= \int_0^\infty t \frac{e^{-t}}{1-e^{-3t}}dt
=\int_0^\infty t \left(\sum_{k=0}^\infty e^{-(3k+1)t}\right) dt\\
\color{blue}{\text{by Tonelli}\;\rightarrow}\quad &= \sum_{k=0}^\infty \int_0^\infty te ^{-(3k+1)t} dt\\
&= \sum_{k=0}^\infty \frac{1}{(3k+1)^2}
= \frac19 \sum_{k=0}^\infty \frac{1}{(k+\frac13)^2}\\
&= \frac19 \zeta\left(2,\frac13\right)
\end{align}
$$
where $\zeta( s, q ) = \sum_{n=0}^\infty \frac{1}{(n+q)^s}$ is the [Hurwitz Zeta function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hurwitz_zeta_function).

Throw the expression `1/9*HurwitzZeta[2,1/3]` to [WA](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=1%2F9*HurwitzZeta[2%2C1%2F3]), the integral
$$\approx 1.121733013936343786865778233321390706724322679920108682437964$$

Comment: Very thanks much @achillehui  I take notes now and in some hours I will close the question.

Comment: This is very nice approach ! Thanks for providing it.

Comment: I choose achille's answer,  honestly I understand it better, but I hope in future times to try put on game your method. Thanks @ClaudeLeibovici como venía a decir Seneca en *Cartas a Lucilio*, el gladiador no hace estrategias antes de ir a la arena, espera a ver qué condiciones y armas tiene su oponente,  incluso la caída de cuerpo de éste,  solo entonces actúa. En resumen habéis demostrado ser unos gladiadores de las matemáticas porque....los gladiadores no hacen futurizos.

Answer (score 0):

Conserning $$I=\int\frac{\log z}{z^3-1}dz$$ I think that the problem becomes simpler if we are allowed to use the fact that $$\int\frac{\log z}{z-a_i}dz=\text{Li}_2\left(\frac{z}{a_i}\right)+\log (z) \log \left(1-\frac{z}{a_i}\right)$$ which makes $$\int_0^1\frac{\log z}{z-a_i}dz=\text{Li}_2\left(\frac{1}{a}\right)$$ provided that $\Im(a_i)\neq 0\lor \Re(a_i)\geq 1\lor \Re(a_i)\leq 0$,  using for the $a_i$'s  $$a_1= 1,\quad a_2= -(-1)^{1/3},\quad a_3=
   (-1)^{2/3}$$ So, partial fraction decomposition and, by the end, this makes $$I=\int_0^1\frac{\log z}{z^3-1}dz=\frac{4 \pi ^2}{81}+\frac{2 \psi ^{(1)}\left(\frac{1}{3}\right)}{27}-\frac{\psi
   ^{(1)}\left(\frac{2}{3}\right)}{27}$$

Comment: Very thanks much too to you @ClaudeLeibovici, I invite to you and previous user if you want discuss some detail, since you are professionals,  I hace that real and write notes on your answer.